# Can't show/hide buttons in the main window of my C++ Win32 app

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a basic button in case: WM_CREATE in the windows procedure with the following.

```
/*The "new_game_button" is declared as type HWND at the 
start of the windows procedure function but not initialized.*/ 
new_game_button = CreateWindow ( "BUTTON", "New Game",
                                  WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER ,
                                  50, 50, 100, 100,
                                  hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

My intent is to create an instructions and "start new game" button as the first thing in my simple tictactoe app. It will immediately show as expected if I give the parameter WS_VISIBLE.

Further in the same case:WM_CREATE if I use the lines

```
if (!start_Game){ //global variable default is false
      ShowWindow( new_game_button, SW_SHOW);
}
```

The button will show as expected.

Outside of those two cases I cannot get the button to show at a later stage.

Further, if I use one of those two methods to show the button I can never get it to go away using

```
ShowWindow ( new_game_button, SW_HIDE);
```

Once the button is showing, it stays for the duration of the programs execution. Doesn't matter which case. Command/Create/Paint

I have tried using

```
if (start_Game){
      ShowWindow( new_game_button, SW_HIDE);
      UpdateWindow ( new_game_button );
      //UpdateWindow ( hwnd ); tried this as well 
}
```

inside case WM_CREATE.

I have also tried the same SW_HIDE line inside case: WM_COMMAND where a new game is generated (compiles but doesn't hide the button.)

I have tried declaring the button child window outside the WM_CREATE inside the windows procedure function. Then using WM_CREATE to show the window - works -- still WM_COMMAND will not hide the window.

I have also tried creating the button window inside of case:WM_PAINT which works to show the button but not to get rid of it. I have even tried DestroyWindow which just fails. [returns 0]

In trying to understand the behaviour of the button window - I have found that I cannot get

`ShowWindow( new_game_button, SW_SHOW);`
to work in the case:WM_COMMAND.

Comment: Are you checking the value of `new_game_button`?  If it is declared in more than one scope then it could be valid in one scope, undefined in the others.

Comment: if `new_game_button` is a valid handle, try checking what function `ShowWindow` returns when hiding the window in the `WM_COMMAND` heartbeat case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it appears that the value is constantly changing @Dave

Answer (score 0):

You said (in a code comment in the question).

> `new_game_button` is declared as type `HWND` at the start of the windows procedure function but not initialized.

Each incoming message means a new call to your window procedure.  Variables which are local to a function don't retain their value between calls unless they are marked `static`.

When your window procedure returned from processing `WM_CREATE`, you lost the value of `new_game_button`.  When you try to use it during `WM_COMMAND` processing later, it is uninitialized and your program causes **undefined behavior** by passing it to `ShowWindow`.

Comment: Ok I understand what is happening - that is I know why its not working. Comment above got me to cout the value of "new_game_button" to the terminal and of course it is constantly changing. Problem is that I cannot mark it static as a quick fix because the program pops up the command window but not the main window.

Comment: @Paulus You can refer to controls by `HWND` or ID. If you cannot save the `HWND`, just use IDs (which you get to choose, [with restrictions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041214-00/?p=37013)). You get back to the `HWND` by calling [`GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem).

Comment: @Paulus: Are you sharing the window procedure between two very different windows?

Answer (score 0):

Every comment helped me solve this which I appreciate. I am too new to give reputation sadly.

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
      new_game_button = CreateWindow ("BUTTON", "New Game",
                                       WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER ,
                                       50, 50, 100, 100,
                                       hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
      if (!start_Game){
            ShowWindow( new_game_button, SW_SHOW);
      }

}
break;
```

After I had an ID for the dialog I am able to use GetDlgItem function to show or hide as I please.

```
new_game_button = GetDlgItem (hwnd, 1);
ShowWindow( new_game_button, SW_HIDE);
```